# Unfiltering partially is disproportionally slow in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, excel-filter

I have an (admittedly pretty large) spreadsheet (around 80,000 rows of around 200 columns). It does not contain any formulas.

Excel has a very weird behaviour of (un-)filtering and I'd like to know what is going on under the hood and how I could fix it:

- Filtering column `B` for value `1` is fast (few seconds).
- Filtering column `C` for value `2` is also very fast.
- Filtering column `B` and then column `C` as well.
- Unfiltering everything is very fast.
- Filtering column `B` and `C` and then unfiltering column `C` takes forever (few minutes).

Why is it that Excel just doesn't unfilter everything and then refilter column `C` which would be "very fast" * 2?

Unfiltering and refiltering is unintuitive for me (and especially others) as an end-user. Could I use a VBA macro of some sort to overwrite the default behaviour **of the filtering menu** (whatever it is that excel does in the background)? *I explicetly do not want a seperate button and input field or similar things.*

*Other questions' ([Excel filtering very slow](https://superuser.com/questions/1126745/excel-filtering-very-slow), [Improving Excel poor filtering performance [closed]](https://superuser.com/questions/1115104/improving-excel-poor-filtering-performance)) answers blame it on formatting or formulas, which I have already checked. Also it seems like they are complaining about the filter performance in general and not the performance of partial unfiltering.*

Comment: record a macro of the actions you mention above and see if it's any better, check out this link for the steps https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+record+a+macro+in+excel&sxsrf=ALeKk01oQoHyk93cYQvOw5TIg0Y2JF7BNg%3A1620113110320&source=hp&ei=1vaQYI61EKm7gwfLg4egAw&iflsig=AINFCbYAAAAAYJEE5ksWvaE_VLdYf9J4mZ4KkI97I59J&oq=how+to+record+a+ma&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMYADICCAAyAggAMgIIADICCAAyAggAMgIIADICCAAyAggAMgIIADICCAA6BAgjECc6CAgAELEDEIMBOgsILhCxAxDHARCjAjoFCAAQsQNQzwFYryJgySpoAHAAeACAAdUBiAHuEpIBBjUuMTIuMZgBAKABAaoBB2d3cy13aXo&sclient=gws-wiz

Comment: @PeterH Making a macro doing these steps is not an issue for me, I'd like to bind it to the filtering menu somehow and I'm not sure if this is possible. (Should have clarified that, edited my question now)

Comment: Ahh ok, you might be able to somehow make the macro a change event so that it is triggered when ever a certain action is taken place, hopefully someone else will be able to help more than me

Comment: What is the file format of your workbook? Applecross binary files (.xlsb) work better with big amount of data.

Comment: I've already converted to `.xlsb` before asking the question. It did help a bit, but not enough ;)

Comment: What version of Excel are you using? 365 / 2019 / 2016? Can you check if it makes a difference on different versions? Is it perhaps a MAC/Windows issues? Silly suggestion, is your windows region settings anything else than English (USA)?

Comment: Did a quick test on my Windows PC on a rather slow spreadsheet with ~2000 rows on Excel 2016. Cant tell a difference in filtering speeds, but maybe I need more rows.

Comment: @Mobus I believe its 2016 on Windows 10. Excel does scale really bad sometimes, I think it has something to do with the fact that it tries to rerender everything after the filtering is done for one row at a time, which would drastically increase the number of operations. I have also noticed that refiltering directly is snappy as well (column `C` filtered with value `2` to value `5` is faster than allowing every value and the filtering afterwards)

Comment: Are you able to see if you have the same issue on a different version, perhaps on an old computer? Can you share a copy of the sheet so we can test it as well?